# Only hardcoded strings must be escaped in PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, unix, escaping

I recently changed servers from Ubuntu to UNIX. On the Ubuntu install of MySQL and PHP, all strings needed to be escaped before inserted into the database, and were read from the database without extra escape characters. However, on the new system, strings that users enter into forms, when untouched, are inserted into the database fine when not escaped. If escaped, extra characters are added. But then I need to add an  tag to the user-entered string with a simple .= and the string refused to be entered into the database unless escaped. And the original user-entered part of the string had extra escape characters. Is there any sort of easy solution for this?
(PHP 5.2.17, MySQL 5.1, Apache 2.2.19)

Comment: maybe "Prepared Statements" are the better solution for you? Prepared statements don't need to be escaped, this will be done automatically for you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a simple .="? And have you checked your php.ini to see that `magic_quotes_gpc` is off?

Comment: A "simple .=" being the variable $post was passed from a form to the php file and I have the command "$post.="<img src='whatever' />";". And magic_quotes_gpc is on, and whether or not I can turn it off is debatable (as the server is not mine, but a "rented" one).

Comment: I believe you should check your configuration file. There should be an option to do this automatically without needing to call it explicitly. Let us know what the configuration for, I believe its called `real_magic_escape_quotes` or something like that, is for you.

Comment: Andy, I believe you're probably also referring to what Joe5150 was talking about. As for prepared statements, using that technique yielded exactly the same results...

Comment: @Jon - Ubuntu is a version of UNIX. So you problems/issues are to do with configuration. BTW - What UNIX system are you now using HPUX, Solaris, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description about **magic quotes** and why it affects your script is [here](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). Basically, this feature affects user input from the browser, but not other strings you create yourself.

Sounds like the relevant setting `magic_quotes_gpc` was off on your old server, but activated on the new one. I always remove magic quotes depending on the setting during runtime, to have the same setup on all machines, even if I can not control `php.ini`.

Try putting this in a central include file before any input parameter processing:

```
// Strip slashes from a string or array recursively
function stripshashesr($text)
{
    if (is_array($text))
    {
        foreach($text as $key => $value) $text[$key]=stripshashesr($value);
        return $text;
    }
    return stripslashes($text);
}

// Strip slashes from GPC
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value) $_GET[$key]=stripshashesr($value);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key]=stripshashesr($value);
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value) $_REQUEST[$key]=stripshashesr($value);
    foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value) $_COOKIE[$key]=stripshashesr($value);
}
```

This removes magic quotes automatically depending on the setting.